# HTML X JavaScript X Google Charts - Change chart according to radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm trying to create an HTML page where a person can visualize a chart drawn with the Google Charts library according to the radio button selected out of 4. I have the radio buttons defined along with the chart calls. However, i'm having a couple of issues. When i first open the page, it doesn't show the chart for the radio option value which is selected by default ("global" in this case which then calls "drawGlobal()") like it's supposed to. And when i try to choose another option, it shows the same chart over and over (which is drawn with "drawBasic3()") instead of opening the corresponding one. If anyone could help me get around this, i would appreciate it!

Here is my code btw:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Global Sentiment Page V2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script>
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(checkValue);

    function drawGlobal() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Sentiment');

      data.addRows([
        ['31/01/2016', 20],
        ['28/02/2016', 35],
        ['31/03/2016', 40],
        ['30/04/2016', 55],
        ['31/05/2016', 60],
        ['30/06/2016', 75],
        ['31/07/2016', 80],
        ['31/08/2016', 95],
        ['30/09/2016', 100]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Average Sentiment Over Time',
        colors : [ '#0000FF', '#00FFFF' ],
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Sentiment',
          viewWindow : {
                    max : 0,
                    min : 100
                }
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_global'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawBasic() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Male');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Female');

      data.addRows([
        ['31/01/2016', 10, 5],
        ['28/02/2016', 25, 15],
        ['31/03/2016', 30, 20],
        ['30/04/2016', 45, 35],
        ['31/05/2016', 50, 40],
        ['30/06/2016', 65, 55],
        ['31/07/2016', 70, 60],
        ['31/08/2016', 85, 75],
        ['30/09/2016', 100, 90]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Average Sentiment Over Time By Gender',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Sentiment'
        },
        colors: ['#00008B', '#0000FF'],
        legend: 'bottom'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawBasic2() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'East');
      data.addColumn('number', 'West');

      data.addRows([
        ['31/01/2016', 2, 8],
        ['28/02/2016', 10, 16],
        ['31/03/2016', 18, 24],
        ['30/04/2016', 26, 31],
        ['31/05/2016', 34, 39],
        ['30/06/2016', 42, 47],
        ['31/07/2016', 50, 55],
        ['31/08/2016', 58, 63],
        ['30/09/2016', 66, 71]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Average Sentiment Over Time By Location',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Sentiment'
        },
        colors: ['#006400', '#008000'],
        legend: 'bottom'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawBasic3(){

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', '0-30');
      data.addColumn('number', '31-60');
      data.addColumn('number', '61+');

      data.addRows([
        ['31/01/2016', 2, 8, 10],
        ['28/02/2016', 10, 16, 18],
        ['31/03/2016', 18, 24, 26],
        ['30/04/2016', 26, 31, 33],
        ['31/05/2016', 34, 39, 42],
        ['30/06/2016', 42, 47, 49],
        ['31/07/2016', 50, 55, 57],
        ['31/08/2016', 58, 63, 65],
        ['30/09/2016', 66, 71, 73]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Average Sentiment Over Time By Age Range',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Sentiment'
        },
        colors: ['#FF7F50', '#FA8072', '#FFA500'],
        legend: 'bottom'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div3'));
      chart.draw(data, options);


    }

    function checkValue()
    {
        switch(document.test.field.value)
        {

            case "global":

                document.getElementById("chartdest").innerHTML = "<div id ='chart_div_global'></div>";
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGlobal);
                drawGlobal();

            case "gender":

                document.getElementById("chartdest").innerHTML = "<div id ='chart_div'></div>";
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
                drawBasic();

            case "location":

                document.getElementById("chartdest").innerHTML = "<div id ='chart_div2'></div>";
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic2);
                drawBasic2();

            case "age":

                document.getElementById("chartdest").innerHTML = "<div id ='chart_div3'></div>";
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic3);
                drawBasic3();
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
#global{
    width: 88.5%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.75%;
    padding-right: 0.75%;
    margin: auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}

input[type=radio] {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>

<div id="global" class = "container">
    <h2 align="left">Charts</h2>
    <br></br>

    <form name='test'>
    <label>Choose type:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="global" onChange="checkValue()" checked>Global 
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="gender" onChange="checkValue()">Gender 
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="location" onChange="checkValue()">Location
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="age" onChange="checkValue()">Age Range      
    </form>

    <br></br>

    <div id='chartdest'>
    </div>

</div>
</center>      
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `switch` statement needs a `break` after each `case`
without the `break`, all charts, beginning with the selected, were being drawn
resulting in the last chart in the sequence...

also, recommend calling `setOnLoadCallback` once per page load
in the following working example, it is set in the `load` statement...

```js
  google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: checkValue,
    packages: ['corechart', 'bar']
  });

    function drawGlobal() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Sentiment');

      data.addRows([
        ['31/01/2016', 20],
        ['28/02/2016', 35],
        ['31/03/2016', 40],
        ['30/04/2016', 55],
        ['31/05/2016', 60],
        ['30/06/2016', 75],
        ['31/07/2016', 80],
        ['31/08/2016', 95],
        ['30/09/2016', 100]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Average Sentiment Over Time',
        colors : [ '#0000FF', '#00FFFF' ],
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Sentiment',
          viewWindow : {
                    max : 0,
                    min : 100
                }
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartdest'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawBasic() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Male');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Female');

      data.addRows([
        ['31/01/2016', 10, 5],
        ['28/02/2016', 25, 15],
        ['31/03/2016', 30, 20],
        ['30/04/2016', 45, 35],
        ['31/05/2016', 50, 40],
        ['30/06/2016', 65, 55],
        ['31/07/2016', 70, 60],
        ['31/08/2016', 85, 75],
        ['30/09/2016', 100, 90]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Average Sentiment Over Time By Gender',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Sentiment'
        },
        colors: ['#00008B', '#0000FF'],
        legend: 'bottom'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartdest'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawBasic2() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'East');
      data.addColumn('number', 'West');

      data.addRows([
        ['31/01/2016', 2, 8],
        ['28/02/2016', 10, 16],
        ['31/03/2016', 18, 24],
        ['30/04/2016', 26, 31],
        ['31/05/2016', 34, 39],
        ['30/06/2016', 42, 47],
        ['31/07/2016', 50, 55],
        ['31/08/2016', 58, 63],
        ['30/09/2016', 66, 71]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Average Sentiment Over Time By Location',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Sentiment'
        },
        colors: ['#006400', '#008000'],
        legend: 'bottom'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartdest'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawBasic3(){

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', '0-30');
      data.addColumn('number', '31-60');
      data.addColumn('number', '61+');

      data.addRows([
        ['31/01/2016', 2, 8, 10],
        ['28/02/2016', 10, 16, 18],
        ['31/03/2016', 18, 24, 26],
        ['30/04/2016', 26, 31, 33],
        ['31/05/2016', 34, 39, 42],
        ['30/06/2016', 42, 47, 49],
        ['31/07/2016', 50, 55, 57],
        ['31/08/2016', 58, 63, 65],
        ['30/09/2016', 66, 71, 73]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Average Sentiment Over Time By Age Range',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Sentiment'
        },
        colors: ['#FF7F50', '#FA8072', '#FFA500'],
        legend: 'bottom'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartdest'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function checkValue()
    {
        switch(document.test.field.value)
        {

            case "global":
                drawGlobal();
                break;

            case "gender":
                drawBasic();
                break;

            case "location":
                drawBasic2();
                break;

            case "age":
                drawBasic3();
                break;

        }
    }
```

```css
#global{
    width: 88.5%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.75%;
    padding-right: 0.75%;
    margin: auto;
    clear: none;
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}

input[type=radio] {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="global" class = "container">
    <h2 align="left">Charts</h2>
    <br></br>

    <form name="test">
    <label>Choose type:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="global" onChange="checkValue()" checked>Global
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="gender" onChange="checkValue()">Gender
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="location" onChange="checkValue()">Location
        <input type="radio" name="field" value="age" onChange="checkValue()">Age Range
    </form>

    <br></br>

    <div id="chartdest">
    </div>

</div>
```